# Prolog - Term replacement, Term alteration in workflow graphs

Tags: replace, prolog

In this link ( [Meta Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119023/un-trivial-prolog-find-and-replace) ) I believe to have found a nifty way of solving a problem I have to tackle, but since my prolog is very bad I'd first ask if its even possible what I have in mind.

I want to transform certain parts of a workflow/graph depending on a set of rules. A graph basically consists of sequences (a->b) and split/joins, which are either parallel or conditional, i.e. two steps run in parallel in the workflow or a single branch is picked depending on a condition (the condition itself does not matter on this level)  (parallel-split - (a && b) - parallel-join) etc. Now a graph usually has nodes and edges, with the form of using terms I want to get rid of edges.

Furthermore each node has a partner attribute, specifying who will execute it.

I'll try to give a simple example what I want to achieve:

A node called A, executed by a partner X, connected with a node called B, executed by a partner Y.

```
A_X -> B_Y
seq((A,X),(B,Y))
```

If I detect a pattern like this, i.e. two steps in sequence with different partners, I want this to be replaced with:

```
A_X -> Send_(X-Y) -> Receive_(Y-X) - B_Y // send step from X to Y and a receive step at Y waiting for something from X

seq((A,X), seq(send(X-Y), seq(receive(Y-X), B)))
```

If anyone could give me some pointers or help to come up with a solution I would be very thankful!

Comment: I've read through your question a couple of times now, and find that it is difficult to follow.  Probably the presentation suffers from a notation that is infelicitous, so I'd recommend spending a bit of time to try and invent a more descriptive yet concise notation.  The example concludes by rewriting `seq((A,X),(B,Y))` with a term `seq((A,X),seq(send(X-Y),seq(receive(Y-X),B)))`.  If this is indeed the pattern you need to implement as a rewrite rule, I can help with that.  However it certainly doesn't appear to be any sort of simplification, so I'm concerned about termination of such rules.

Comment: @hardmath, I am aware that it is not a simplification. Basically what I have are 2 activities in a workflow, in simplest form a sequence, i.e. seq(activity(A,PA), activity(B,PB)), where activity(Name, Partner) name is obvious, just some ID and partner is the executing partner in a remote environment. When I now detect that PA!=PB, i.e. the steps are not executed at the same partner, then what I need to do is add a send activity to partner A and a corresponding receive activity to partner B. If you are really up for helping me, please just dropme an e-mail to exchange some IM contact info.

Comment: @mardmath since I ran out of space, the rule shall terminate when the nested sequence term ends. I am tryting to write a predicate in the form t(InputWOrkflow, OutputWorkflow, Partner), so an example could be t(seq(act(a,x),seq(act(b,y),act(c,y))), O, y). 
Now since there is act(a,x) followed by act(b,y) the partners are different (x!=y), thus I want to add add these send and receive activites into the nested terms.

Answer (score 0):

> A graph basically consists of sequences (a->b) and split/joins, which are either parallel or conditional, i.e. two steps run in parallel in the workflow or a single branch is picked depending on a condition

This sounds an awful lot like an [and/or graph](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/AI2/node25.html). Prolog algorithms on these graphs are covered by Ivan Bratko in [*Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Prolog_programming_for_artificial_intell.html?id=-15su78YRj8C), chapter 13. Even if your graphs aren't really and/or graphs, you may be able to adapt some of these algorithms to your task.